# I want to get an average of ESG values in each category for each year per continent. I can't seem to hack it as I started coding a few days ago

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean

```
   Country Name                                Series Name     Year     ESG Value
0   China   CO2 emissions (metric tons per capita)          2012    7.046182675
1   China   Control of Corruption: Estimate                 2012    -0.438275933
2   China   Energy use (kg of oil equivalent per capita)    2012    2149.602569
3   China   Electricity production from coal sources (% of..2012    75.65891205
4   China   Energy imports, net (% of energy use)           2012    14.35974038
```

So basically these are just the first 5 values. I have a total of 10 countries, 29 Series Names (categories), Year 2012~2021, and a bunch of ESG values for every category for every year for every country (if that makes sense).

I am trying to code so that I can find the mean of each category from 2012 to 2021 for each country. An example would be "China - CO2 emissions - Year 2012~2021 - ESG mean = 234234.3243" "China - Control of Corruption - Year 2012~2021 - ESG mean = 99349.32"

I tried to use the groupby function to find the mean using certain variables. For example:

mean_value = df.groupby('Series Name')[['Year', 'ESG Value']].mean()
print(mean_value)

The result is something I have no idea what it means...

```
                                                    Year
Series Name                                             
Access to electricity (% of population)              inf
Annualized average growth rate in per capita re...   inf
CO2 emissions (metric tons per capita)               inf
Children in employment, total (% of children ag...   inf
Control of Corruption: Estimate                      inf
Ease of doing business rank (1=most business-fr...   inf
Electricity production from coal sources (% of ...   inf
Energy imports, net (% of energy use)                inf
Energy use (kg of oil equivalent per capita)         inf
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you need the average of the ESG values you need to take only "ESG Value"

```
mean_of_ESG_Value=df["ESG Value"].mean()
```